# Использование метода map в React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я только выучил новый для себя хук useState и у меня есть проблема... 
Сейчас полетят тухлые помидоры в экран но я поставил себе задачу и не могу ёё решить. 
Суть: есть обычное поле input в которое пользователь должен вводить кокой либо текст и после нажатия на кнопку текст должен отобразится на экране ( типо todo list ). 
Проблема: Я посмотрел пару видео о даном хуке но научился я только самого банального ( делать счетчик и все по сути )

На даном примере кода я начал разработку задуманого но незнаю как присобачить веденное с инпута в переменную состояния хука "state, input"

Я не знаю что делать но я не понимаю логики хука, просьба не писать чтобы я внимательно читал документацию так как уже читал ее по несколько раз

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function App() {

    const [state, setState] = useState([])
    const [input, setInput] = useState('')

    function handleClick() {
        setState([...state, input])
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={input} onChange={setState} />
            <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>Touch</button>
            <div>
                {
                    state.map()
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

В инпуте в атрибуте `onChange` вызывается `setState`, но значение не передаётся. Должно быть `setState(value)`. После вызова с передачечей `value`, значение будет храниться в переменной `state`. Соответственно при клике обработчиком должна быть callback-функция, которая возьмёт из переменной `value` значение (оно будет равно тому, что было введено в инпуте).

Пример:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function App() {

    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])
    const [input, setInput] = useState('')

    function clickHandler() {
        const value = input // input доступен отсюда
        // ... далее обращение к API или то что нужно
        // например, копируем туду, которые были и добавляем новую
        setTodos([...todos, value])
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input onChange={setInput(this.value)} />
            <button className="btn" onClick={clickHandler}>Add todo</button>
            <div>
                {
                    todos.map(todo => (<><div>{todo}</div><br/></>))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

1. метод state.map() пустой
   2)setState у вас передает событие а не значение

   import React, { useState } from 'react';
   function App() {
   const [state, setState] = useState([])
   const [input, setInput] = useState('')

   ```
        function handleClick() {
            setState([...state, input])
        }
        function handleInput(event){
            setInput(event.target.value);
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <input value={input} onChange={handleInput} />
                <button className="btn" onClick={handleClick}>Touch</button>
                <div>
                    {state.map(function(el){return <div>{el}</div>})}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default App
   ```

как то так надо